# Create Object in Specific loaction in Array Powershell

Tags: arrays, object, powershell

I was wondering if you could help me on this one. I have an array of objects in powershell containing this:

```
$array = @(1,2,3,4,5)
```

so `$array` gives me this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

now i would like to add in the number 6 on the position `$array[3],` so that the output would be:

```
1
2
3
6
4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. Ex.

```
PS > $i = 1..5

PS > $i
#ouput
1
2
3
4
5

PS > function insertInto ($array, $index, $value) {
    @($array[0..($index-1)],$value,$array[$index..($array.length-1)])
}

PS > $i = insertInto $i 3 6

PS > $i
#output
1
2
3
6
4
5
```

Warning, the method above is not very good for single value arrays.